# Print the fist row with check the condition in awk command

Tags: linux, awk

File in content is

```
safwan@hello:~/linx$ cat 5.txt 
Name    age address email
safwan  25  India   safwan@gmail.com
Ajmal   23  India   ajmal@gmil.com
```

Apply a condition

```
awk '$2==25 {print}' 5.txt
```

output is

```
safwan@hello:~/linx$ awk '$2==25 {print}' 5.txt 
safwan  25  India   safwan@gmail.com
```

But I need also the first row

I expect the output is like

```
Name    age address email
safwan  25  India   safwan@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate if `NR == 1` or your actual condition to get the header row with your data row:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 || $2 == 25' 5.txt
```

Besides there is no need to use `{print}` as that is the default action in `awk`.

Comment: @safwanpaloli: Did this work out?